# How to authenticate/login before a REST request on Payara?

Tags: java, security, authentication, jakarta-ee, payara

In order to allow REST method execution in a Java EE 7 application only for certain users I understood that I have to

- annotate the RESTful bean with `@RolesAllowed`, e.g. `@RolesAllowed("project1")`
- add role mapping to the deployment descriptor similar to

  ```
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
       <web-resource-name>restbean</web-resource-name>
       <url-pattern>/rest/restbean</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
       <role-name>project1</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
      <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
      <realm-name>jaxrs</realm-name>
  </login-config>

  <security-role>
      <role-name>project1</role-name>
  </security-role>
  ```

But what then? I assume I have to define the user `project1` in the `file` realm on the server (Payara 4.1.2.174 in my case) and restart. I then expect that the browser asks the `project1` credentials when I access the RESTful URL in Firefox, but instead it still fails due to

```
INFORMATION:   JACC Policy Provider: Failed Permission Check, context(project1-web/project1-web_internal)- permission(("javax.security.jacc.EJBMethodPermission" "OfferDevRest" "createRandomOfferIncognito,Local,"))
WARNUNG:   A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB OfferDevRest, method: public javax.ws.rs.core.Response richtercloud.project1.web.rest.dev.OfferDevRest.createRandomOfferIncognito()
WARNUNG:   javax.ejb.AccessLocalException: Client not authorized for this invocation
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.preInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1976)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:210)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:90)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy248.createRandomOfferIncognito(Unknown Source)
    at richtercloud.project1.web.rest.dev.__EJB31_Generated__OfferDevRest__Intf____Bean__.createRandomOfferIncognito(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1692)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:339)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:251)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:593)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:483)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with additional mapping in glassfish-web.xml by Karl Richter is correct.

Alternatively, it's possible to add a user to a group and map the group to a role automatically. Adding more users to the role wouldn't require any changes in the application, only in the realm on the server.

Here's what to do:
- edit the user `project1` in the `jaxrs` realm and add it to the `project1admin` group
- enable the option "Default Principal To Role Mapping" in the Security page in Admin console. This will add all users to roles with the same name as their groups - user `project1` will be given the role `project1admin` derived from its group

With the above steps, you don't need any role mapping in the `glassfish-web.xml` file and you can delete the file if you don't needed it for something else.

See the documentation for the [default group to role mapping in Payara Server](https://docs.payara.fish/v/174/documentation/extended-documentation/app-deployment/descriptor-elements.html#default-role-mapping).

Note that this functionality is only supported in Payara Server and not in GlassFish Server, while the solution with `security-role-mapping` configurations in `glassfish-web.xml` is supported also by GlassFish, but it's much more complex.

Answer (score 2):

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>project1admin</role-name>
    <principal-name>project1</principal-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```

needs to be added to `glassfish-web.xml` in `WEB-INF` and the `url-pattern` didn't match the requested URL in my case.